# what is the summation from i=0 to log(n)

Tags: summation, logarithms

I need to know how to get the summation of a constant (c) from i=0 to log(n) of a constant

Comment: $\;\log n-1\;$ won't usually be a natural number, so what do you *exactly* mean?

Comment: Maybe there's a ceiling or flooring operation on $\log(n) - 1$, for $n>0$?

Comment: Your question is not enough clear !

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It's important that posts are clearly written in TeX and explained so users can help as much as possible!

Comment: sorry its a typo, it is without -1 @DonAntonio

Comment: $C\log(n)$ when $\log(n)$ is natural, otherwise it is sometimes considered abuse of notation unless rigorously defined; where it still equals $C\log(n)$.

Comment: @Alexandralopez That doesn't matter: the number's still not a natural one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{\ln(n)} C = C \sum_{i = 0}^{\ln(n)} 1 = C\cdot (\ln(n)+1) = C\ln(n) + C $$

**"More rigorously"**

$$\lim_{N\to \ln(n)} \sum_{i = 0}^{N} C = C\cdot (N+1) = C\ln(n) + C$$

Comment: there are $\log(n) + 1$ indices when starting from zero. So it's $C(\log(n)+1)$. The sum is $\sum_{j=0}^{\log(n)-1} C = C\log(n)$.

Comment: @james.nixon Whoops, thank you!